# Show loading gif while child process task is performed and hide when complete

Tags: node.js, child-process

Hello I am looking for assistance with displaying a loading gif while my route performs a task. I already have a promise function that displays a message when the test is running and than displays a message when it is done. I'm thinking I can incorporate the loading gif along with it. I am just not sure how to go about it with this set up.

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img src="/images/loading.gif" height="32" width="32" id="loading-indicator" style="display: none ; margin: 0 auto;" />
</div>
```

The sever side, using node.js with express.

```
router.get("/pos/fcsf_default", (req, res) => {
let test = "Was a super long string, edited to read easier."
let data = JSON.stringify(test);

  sendToSlack("QA Hub - Automation - FCSF: " + req.user.username + " is running a rental with default values(This is a test)", "QA Hub - Automation", "auto_message_test" );
  console.log("QA Hub - Automation - FCSF: " + req.user.username + " is running a rental with default values", "QA Hub - Automation", "auto_message_test");

  var child = exec(`cd ${__dirname} & cd ../../ & cd automation_projects/fcsf/ & rake reserve`);

  fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../", "temp/form-data.json"), (data));

  myPromise(child).then(function (result) {
     console.log('promise complete: ' + result);
     sendToSlack("QA Hub - Automation - FCSF: " +  "Test complete.");
     console.log("QA Hub - Automation - FCSF: " +  "Test complete.")
  }, function (err) {
     console.log('promise rejected: ' + err);
     sendToSlack("Test failed");
  });

      req.flash("info", data + " test is being sent to process and run.");
      res.redirect("/QAApplicationHub/Automation/dispatch_receive");
})
```

Ive read using ajax, is that the best approach here? I'm thinking what has to be done is retrieve the image from the server side and than send it to the front end so that I can show it on the UI and trigger it from this route....Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Show the image before lauching the .get request, then inside when it's completed, hide it.